# My custom Windows Service not working with Windows Message Queue

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

The windows service i coded is not working:

- Intended funcionality: The service is supposed to receive messages from Windows Message Queue (MSMQ) and write the messages on .txt files.
- It works when I run it not-as-a-service (directly from visual studio)
- When I installed it as a service i can start it, but it doesn't do anything, not creating/writing .txt files anywhere

(I know it isn't writing the files elsewhere because when I run the program from VS the messages are still in the queue, so they weren't taken out by the service)

The difference between running it as a service and running it from visual studio is the next:

```
namespace ComponentAtrapador
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        static void Main()
        {
#if DEBUG
            Service1 myService = new Service1();
            myService.startMethod();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);


#else
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
            { 
                new Service1() 
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
#endif
        }
    }
}
```

(so if i run it as DEBUG it will run without me having to install it as a service)

Here's the service's code:

```
namespace ComponentAtrapador
{
        public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
        {
        private System.Timers.Timer _timer;
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components1;
        private System.Diagnostics.EventLog eventLog1;

        public void startMethod()
        {
           OnStart(null);
        }
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            eventLog1 = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();
            if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("MySource"))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(
                    "MySource", "MyNewLog");
            }
            eventLog1.Source = "MySource";
            eventLog1.Log = "MyNewLog";
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("In OnStart");
                _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
                _timer.Interval = 5000; // 5 seconds
                _timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.OnTimer);
                _timer.Start();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            _timer.Stop();
        }

        public void OnTimer(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs args)
        {
            string nombreArchivo = "archivoMensaje";
                    MessageQueue messageQueue = new MessageQueue(@".\Private$\SomeTestName");
                    System.Messaging.Message[] messages = messageQueue.GetAllMessages();

                    System.Messaging.Message m = new System.Messaging.Message();
                    foreach (System.Messaging.Message message in messages)
                    {
                        message.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new String[] { "System.String,mscorlib" });
                        string text = message.Body.ToString();
                        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + nombreArchivo + Properties.Settings.Default.SettingNumero + ".txt", text);
                        Properties.Settings.Default.SettingNumero++;
                        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                        //Do something with the message.
                    }
                    // after all processing, delete all the messages
                    messageQueue.Purge();

            //}

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellently crafted question. Thank you.

Comment: When you run as a window service vs running from visual studio, there are two differences that are relevant here. 1) The program will run as local system account by default instead of the logged on user account. 2) The working directory is system32 folder instead of where the exe is.

Comment: Check whether your windows service is configured with an account that can access the private queue @".\Private$\SomeTestName

Comment: Try to change windows service log on account by using service properties screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the service didn't have enough permissions, fixed it by setting the serviceProcessInstaller of the service on visual studio to User, so that when i installed it it'd ask for credentials. Just had to type "./[username]" when it asked for my username for it to work.

Another way of fixing it would be going into the task manager > services > right click service > properties > security. And change the permissions there.

Answer (score 0):

That is where Logs are so helpful, put couple of eventLog1.WriteEntry() inside your OnTimer method and you will see where is it failing.
I would check

1. how many messages I am getting.
2. I will put one eventLog1.WriteEntry() inside loop to see what is happening with each message etc...